# PowerPoint Service Application automatic clean-up

Tags: powerpoint-services

We are currently using a PowerPoint Conversion service application to convert *.pptx to *.pdf. However when using this method, the converted files are cached locally within 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\PowerPointConversion\'.

Does any (SharePoint) service executes a automatic clean-up within this folder?

Comment: The converted files are also saved locally within C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\SharePoint\PowerPointConversion

Comment: The only thing that does an auto clean-up is a self-made script that remove the files from that directory. This can be achieved by PowerShell or basic functions in your favorite CMD.